# What is the relationship between neurotransmitter release and resting potential in retinal bipolar cells?

Tags: neuroscience, vision

Retinal bipolar cells are known to have resting potentials from which they can become more *or* less polarized. What I'm wondering is whether a bipolar cell's neurotransmitter-release rate is zero when it's at resting potential, or whether it's zero when it's fully hyperpolarized.

Answer (score 2):

Bipolar cells reduce transmitter release when hyperpolarized, see the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retina_bipolar_cell#cite_note-isbn0-87893-694-7-1). When the bipolar cell is fully hyperpolarized it will basically stop releasing neurotransmitters. If transmitter release ever becomes totally zero I do not dare to say, however.